# Using GitLab API to limit who can create new branches from protected branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I’m working on automating a repository creation process. I want to have a main branch, along with a set of branches created automatically from it. I’m using python-gitlab but ofc I can use HTTP requests if needed.

My issue is that I do not want developers to be able to branch from main (i.e. they should only work on the unprotected branches, or other branches created from these). They should still be able to create merge requests from the default branches into main. Is there a way to enforce this?

Code for clarity, not really required to understand:

```py
    p_branch = project.protectedbranches.create({
         'name': 'main',
         'merge_access_level': gitlab.MAINTAINER_ACCESS,
         'push_access_level': gitlab.MAINTAINER_ACCESS
     })
    
    
    for branch_name in branch_names:
         branch = project.branches.create({'branch': branch_name, 'ref': 'main'})
```

LE:
It would also mean this option would be disabled when trying to edit a file on the protected branch (not automatically creating this ugly branch name):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add protected branches with the [Protected Branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html).

```sh
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/protected_branches?name=*-stable"
```

This curl commands adds all branches that match the pattern `*-stable` as protected branches. You can also change what roles can merge, push, unprotect branches, etc. using additional attributes listed [in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html#protect-repository-branches).

If you use the defaults, only members with the `Maintainer` role or higher (`Owner`'s) can push to protected branches, merge them, unprotect them, etc.

Note: I'm not sure if there's support for the Protected Branches API in the python library (I don't use it myself), so you might need to write out the requests manually.

Comment: There *is* support for it in the Python library, as you can see from the code snippet in the OP. My question was about who is allowed to *create* a new branch from main, which doesn't seem to be configurable using the attributes in the docs.

Comment: Anyone can create a new branch based on any branch, protected or not. A common flow is to protect your main branch, have developers create branches from main (and rebase onto main when there are upstream changes), then submit a Merge Request to merge back into main.

Comment: I know of this common flow, and it's not what I am intending to use. You can see the flow I want in the OP.